# Rotating 3D plots with the mouse in multiplot mode

Tags: gnuplot

When I do the following in gnuplot ...

```
set terminal x11
splot sin(x)
```

I can rotate the 3d plot with the mouse

On the other hand, if I do the following

```
set terminal x11
set multiplot layout 1,2
splot sin(x)
splot cos(x)
```

I can't rotate sin(x) or cos(x) even though I would love to. Does anybody know if it is possible to create a multiplot with plots that you can rotate?

Comment: You can't, see Ethan's answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/4DJtSJbEfLE

Comment: Thanks. If you want, you can leave this as an answer and I will mark it so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  Ethan A. Merritt, one of the gnuplot developers, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/4DJtSJbEfLE) explained why:

> Fundamental limitation. The "`multiplot`" command is best understood as
>   meaning "don't start a new page for the next plot".  So your commands
>   have created two separate plots, that just happen to be on the same
>   page. Gnuplot only tracks the data for one plot at a time, so you can
>   only redraw the most recent plot.  All earlier plots are long gone.