# gnuplot - how to obtain contour lines with the same level color of the 3d plot

Tags: colors, plot, gnuplot, contour

I have a 3-dimensional plot obtained with gnuplot, for which I also calculate the contour lines as:

> set pm3d at s
>
> set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
>
> set contour
>
> unset clabel
>
> set cntrparam levels incremental 1,1,5
>
> sp "dati.dat" u 1:2:3 w l ls 7 notitle

I'd really like to plot the contour lines with the same colour specified in the corresponding level in the 3d plot. I didn't find any helpful post. Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the `palette` command in the `sp` command:

```
set pm3d at s
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set contour
unset clabel
set cntrparam levels incremental -100,10,100

sp x*y w l ls 7 palette notitle
```

The `palette` option will apply your definition from line `2` to the contour-lines, and you will get this plot:

[image: surface and contour lines]

*Note*: The contour levels were changed to `-100,10,100` to accomodate the function `x*y` which I chose to plot due to the lack of a suitable input file.

---

If you want to keep a black grid on the surface, I suggest using `multiplot` and simply plotting the grid on top of the surface. This is the updated code:

```
set pm3d at s
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set contour
unset clabel
set cntrparam levels incremental -100,10,100

set multiplot

sp x*y w l ls 7 palette notitle

unset contour

sp x*y w l ls 7 notitle

unset multiplot
```

It is important to `unset` the contour between the two plot commands. That way, you will just get the grid with the second `sp` command (and no `palette` option there, either).

And now, the example looks like this:

[image: surface, contour lines and black grid]

---

If you attempt to manually rotate the figure you generate with the `multiplot`-command, you will loose the contour-lines (because they were plotted first), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507727/rotating-3d-plots-with-the-mouse-in-multiplot-mode/17548153#17548153). If the default orientation does not suit your needs, use [`set view`](http://www.manpagez.com/info/gnuplot/gnuplot-4.2.6/gnuplot_291.php) before calling multiplot.